# j2me password field with numeric entry

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

I have used

```
this.passwordTextField = new TextField( "", "", 30, TextField.PASSWORD | TextField.DECIMAL);
```

to get the numeric value password field. but it still takes "#" as an entry and show "." for that at output. but I only need numbers. I also used

```
UiAccess.setInputMode( this.passwordTextField, UiAccess.MODE_NUMBERS);
```

how should i do that?

Answer (score 2):

It also can solved by using

```
  new TextField( "", "", 30, TextField.PASSWORD | TextField.MODE_NUMBERS );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
this.passwordTextField = new TextField( "", "", 30, TextField.PASSWORD | 
TextField.NUMERIC);
```

The textfield constraint with `TextField.DECIMAL` will allow the user to enter characters `-` and `.`, [check this](http://www.enough.de/javadoc/j2me/de/enough/polish/ui/TextField.html#DECIMAL).

You can even be smatter by trying the constraint `TextField.PASSWORD | TextField.NUMERIC | TextField.SENSITIVE`